# How to enable or disable a click on a table row in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to enable or disable a click on a table row in jquery? What I want to accomplish are, when a user click the `edit button`, user **cannot** select/click a table row. When a user click either the `save button` or `cancel button` a user **can** select/click a table row. I already implemented my solution but it is not working. I already put comments where the problem occurs. Here is the link to my code https://jsfiddle.net/Xonnn/ngka3Lh9/2/.

Comment: has nothing to do with your question but why don't you use HTML5 for your project? HTML5 is standard since over 10 years now, no reason to still stick to HTML4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've added a variable `editRowEnable`

This the code will set as true/false depending on if edit row is "active"

Pending on the value of `editRowEnable` then you will be able to select row or not.

**Demo**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var editRowEnable = false;

  function populateInputFields() {
    var currentRow = $("#myTable tr.highlighted");
    var input1 = $("#input1").val(currentRow.find("td:eq(0)").text());
    var input2 = $("#input2").val(currentRow.find("td:eq(1)").text());
    var input3 = $("#input3").val(currentRow.find("td:eq(2)").text());
  }

  function isRowHighlighted() {
    if (!$('input').val()) {
      alert("Please click a row.");
    } else {
      editEnableDisable();
      input1;
      input2;
      input3;
    }
  }

  function editEnableDisable() {
    $("#input1").prop('disabled', false);
    $("#input2").prop('disabled', false);
    $("#input3").prop('disabled', false);
    $("#edit").prop('disabled', true);
    $("#save").prop('disabled', false);
    $("#cancel").prop('disabled', false);
  }

  function saveCancelEnableDisable() {
    $("#input1").prop('disabled', true);
    $("#input2").prop('disabled', true);
    $("#input3").prop('disabled', true);
    $("#edit").prop('disabled', false);
    $("#save").prop('disabled', true);
    $("#cancel").prop('disabled', true);
  }

  function successDialogBox() {
    $("p").text("Case has been updated");
    $("#dialogBox").dialog();
  }

  function updateGridData() {
    enableTableSelection();
    var currentRow = $("#myTable tr.highlighted");
    currentRow.find("td:eq(0)").text($("#input1").val());
    currentRow.find("td:eq(1)").text($("#input2").val());
    currentRow.find("td:eq(2)").text($("#input3").val());

  }

  function revertChanges() {
    var currentRow = $("#myTable tr.highlighted");
    var previous1 = currentRow.find("td:eq(0)").text()
    var previous2 = currentRow.find("td:eq(1)").text()
    var previous3 = currentRow.find("td:eq(2)").text()


    $("#input1").val(previous1);
    $("#input2").val(previous2);
    $("#input3").val(previous3);

  }
  ///ENABLE OR DISABLE CLICK ON TABLE ROWS
  function disableTableSelection() {
    $("#recentCasesTable tr").off('click');
  }

  function enableTableSelection() {
    $("#recentCasesTable tr").on('click');
  }

  $('#myTable tr').click(function() {
    if (!editRowEnable) {
      $('#myTable tr').removeClass('highlighted');
      $(this).addClass('highlighted');
      populateInputFields();
    }
  });

  $("#edit").click(function() {
    editRowEnable = true;
    disableTableSelection(); //This Function is not working
    isRowHighlighted();
  });

  $("#save").click(function() {
    editRowEnable = false;
    enableTableSelection(); //This Function is not working
    updateGridData()
    saveCancelEnableDisable()
    successDialogBox();
  });

  $("#cancel").click(function() {
    editRowEnable = false;
    enableTableSelection(); //This Function is not working
    revertChanges();
    saveCancelEnableDisable();

  });
});
```

```css
#myTable {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 50%;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  padding: 2px;
}

#myTable th {
  padding-top: 12px;
  padding-bottom: 12px;
  text-align: left;
  background-color: #04AA6D;
}

#myTable td,
th {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  padding: 8px;
}

#myTable tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #D8D8D8;
}

#myTable tr.highlighted td {
  background-color: #5c715e;
}

#caseDetailsContainer {
  border-style: solid;
}

fieldset {
  border: 1px solid #04AA6D;
  border-width: thin;
  width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
  <title>TABLE ENABLE DISABLE SELECTION</title>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/script.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />
  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https:/resources/demos/style.css" />
  <link type="text/css" href="Style/style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />
  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https:/resources/demos/style.css" />
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>

</head>

<body>

  <table id="myTable">
    <tr>
      <th>TH 1&nbsp</th>
      <th>TH 2&nbsp</th>
      <th>TH 3&nbsp</th>

    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>R1&nbsp</td>
      <td>R1&nbsp</td>
      <td>R1&nbsp</td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>R2&nbsp</td>
      <td>R2&nbsp</td>
      <td>R2&nbsp</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>R3&nbsp</td>
      <td>R3&nbsp</td>
      <td>R3&nbsp</td>
    </tr>
  </table>

  <fieldset>
    <legend><b>Input Fields</b></legend>
    <table id="caseDetails">
      <tr>
        <td>Department Case #</td>
        <td><input type="text" id="input1" name="input1#" disabled="disabled" / value="" /></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Department</td>
        <td><input type="text" id="input2" name="input2" disabled="disabled" value="" /></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Charge</td>
        <td><input type="text" id="input3" name="input3" disabled="disabled" value="" /></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <br/>
    <button id="edit" name="edit" type="submit" value="edit">Edit</button>
    <button id="save" name="save" type="submit" value="save" disabled="disabled">Save</button>
    <button id="cancel" name="cancel" type="submit" value="cancel" disabled="disabled">Cancel</button>
  </fieldset>

  <div id="dialogBox">
    <p>
    </p>
  </div>


</body>

</html>
```